# problem changing style in a Spinner

Tags: android, coding-style, spinner

i need to implement an application in android using styles. I know that, difining an style for each object in styles.xml, it's possible to stablish diferent styles for: Textview, Buttons, editviews..but in the special case of spinner it doesn't work. this is my example:

this is the layout main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<TextView  
    style="@style/TextviewVerde" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/escribenombre"
    />
<EditText
    style="@style/EditviewAzul"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TxtNombre" 

    />
<Spinner
    style="@style/SpinnerRojo"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TxtSpinner"
    android:prompt="@string/seleccionetexto" 

/>
<Button
    style="@style/BotonBlanco"
    android:id="@+id/BtnHola" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pulse aqui"  
    />   

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="TextviewVerde" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">5pt</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextviewRosa" >
        <item name="android:textColor">#5F04B4</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15pt</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditviewAzul"  >
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8pt</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#0000FF</item>       
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerRojo"  > 
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#DF0101</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11pt</item>
        <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="BotonBlanco">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>     
     </style>

</resources>
```

every object works well, but the spinner doesn't change its appearance. My boss told me that i have to implement styles without changing the *.java file, what can i do?? i need to change the colour of the spinner options, the backgound, add some pics.. etc. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You are overwriting values you've defined in the style. Please be more specific and clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry for the overwriting code, i would like to style a spinner, listview etc( i mean, change the colour of the options, the background etc) without change the *.java code, because i kown that it's possible to change the  spinner's style programatically, but i want to use only styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/

Comment: Thane Anthem, thanks, that's a good answer, but i don't whant to change only the bottom of the spinner, i also want to change the appearance of the dialog of the spinner(the list of options that appears when i click the spinner bottom). what could i do??

Answer (score 0):

To make custom styled dropdown when the spinner is clicked, you should create a custom Adapter with a reference to your layout xml defining the rows of the list.

For example:

```
String[] elements = {"optionA", "optionB"};
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.id.textViewId, elements);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_dropdown_layout);
```

Where textViewId should be a child view in your_dropdown_layout.

Hope that helped.

Ripityom